# Why can't I paste § into a Minecraft command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

According to https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes, using §1 in an item's name should make the text colored dark blue.

However, when I copy-paste a command like this one into chat:

```
/give @p diamond_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"§1Sword\"}"}}
```

it comes out like this:

```
/give @p diamond_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"1Sword\"}"}}
```

See the problem? I can't copy § into chat!

Which means the name ends up being "1Sword" rather than "Sword" colored dark blue.

Why can't I copy § into chat? What can I do to fix it?

Note: I've tested this issue on Minecraft versions 1.14.3 and 1.12.2. It worked the same on both. Feel free to leave a comment if you need more details.

Comment: If you have a number pad (I don't know if you are on a laptop that doesn't have one or not) - ALT + 21 types the § symbol.  I also don't know if Minecraft detects ALT sequences.  It has to be the number pad - not the number line on a keyboard.

Comment: @TimmyJim That's not Minecraft doing it, that's Windows.

Answer (score 10):

You can actually set a color with the `color`-tag inside of the `Name`-tag by using a command like this:

```
/give @p diamond_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Sword\",\"color\":\"dark_blue\"}"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## 1.15 Update

Entering JSON text is now easier in 1.15 because NBT string tags can use single quotes `'`.

Instead of:

```
/give @s dirt{display:{Name:"[{\"text\":\"Earth\", \"color\":\"green\"}]"}}
```

Try:

```
/give @s dirt{display:{Name:'[{"text":"Earth","color":"green"}]'}}
```

Answer (score -3):

Hold on the & symbol and choose it from the menu

Comment: Incorrect. This is not talking about how to get the `§` on a mobile keyboard.